# Wireshark 802.11 packet parsing procedure

Tags: wireshark, wifi

Can anyone explain the procedure involved in parsing a `802.11 packet` using wireshark ? How does wireshark do this ?

Comment: Wireshark is able  to dissect the 802.11 protocol (and other protocols,   e.g. TCP) because it has code which "knows" the structure of that protocol.
Can you be more specific about what you want to know ?

Comment: I want to know the internal procedure / the idea behind the module `libpcap` used in parsing the 802.11 packets. @willyo

Comment: libpcap is an "API for capturing network traffic". It does no parsing of packets.

Comment: I think it does more than that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111479/how-can-i-parse-an-ethernet-packet-using-libpcap @willyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libpcap is an "API for capturing network traffic". It does no parsing of packets.
Wireshark uses libpcap to capture packets which are then dissected (parsed)  by code in Wireshark.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111479/how-can-i-parse-an-ethernet-packet-using-libpcap